# Getting the top wallpaper from reddit

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the hottest Wallpaper from *Reddit's [wallpaper subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers)*.
I am using `beautiful soup` to get the `HTML` layout of the first wallpaper And then `regex` to get the `URL` from the anchor tag. But more than often I get a URL that's not matched by my regex. Here's the code I am using:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers")
if r.status_code == 200:
    print r.status_code
    text = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

search_string = str(soup.find('a', {'class':'title'}))
photo_url = str(re.search('[htps:/]{7,8}[a-zA-Z0-9._/:.]+[a-zA-Z0-9./:.-]+', search_string).group())
```

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a better way to do it:
Adding `.json` to the end of url in *Reddit* returns a `json` object instead of `HTML`.
For example `https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers` will provide HTML content ***but*** 
 `https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/.json` will give you a json object which you can easily exploit using `json` module in python

Here's the same program of getting the hottest wallpaper:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import json

>>> data = urllib.urlopen('https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/.json')
>>> wallpaper_dict = json.loads(data.read())

>>> wallpaper_dict['data']['children'][1]['data']['url']
u'http://i.imgur.com/C49VtMu.jpg'

>>> wallpaper_dict['data']['children'][1]['data']['title']
u'Space Shuttle'

>>> wallpaper_dict['data']['children'][1]['data']['domain']
u'i.imgur.com'
```

Not only it's much more cleaner, it'll also prevent you from a headache if reddit changes it's HTML layout or someone posts a URL that your regex can't handle.
As a thumb rule it's generally smarter to use `json` instead of scraping the `HTML`
PS: The list inside the `[children]` is the wallpaper number. The first one is the topmost, the second one is the second one and so on.
Therefore `['data']['children'][2]['data']['url']` will give you the link for the second hottest wallpaper. you get the gist? :)

PPS: What's more is that with this method you can use the default `urllib` module. Generally when you're scraping `Reddit` you'd have to create fake `User-Agent` header and pass it while requesting(or it gives you a 429 response code but that's not the case with this method.

Comment: Does appending `.json` on other `subreddits`' URL returns json object as well?

Comment: @Hodor Yes it does. On all `subreddits`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct way to do it your method, but Jarwins method is better. You should not be using regex when working with HTML. You simply had to reference the `href` attribute to get the URL

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers")
if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    url = str(soup.find_all('a', {'class':'title'})[1]["href"])
    print url
```